# Generate a List of IPv6 from give subnet-IndexError: range contains more than 2147483647 (sys.maxint) IP addresses! Use the .size property instead

Tags: python, ipv6

This is my 1st post so apology for being noob. I have been trying to generate List from given subnet in python.

### Code

```py
from netaddr import*
import ipcalc
import sys

# Static input, try /125, it will work.

ipv6 = '2402:9400:1000:0::/64'
  

# generating list of IPs

ipv6 = IPNetwork(ipv6)
ip_list6 = list(ipv6)


# Printing list by element

First_IP = str(ip_list6[0])
Last_IP = str(ip_list6[-1])


print ('\nIP range:' + First_IP + '-' + Last_IP)
print ('\n')
```

### Error:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Test.py", line 13, in <module>
    ip_list6 = list(ipv6)
  File "C:\Users\hprajapati\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\netaddr\ip\__init__.py", line 704, in __len__
    "IP addresses! Use the .size property instead." % _sys_maxint))
IndexError: range contains more than 2147483647 (sys.maxint) IP addresses! Use the .size property instead.
```

Comment: Format your code properly please.  Make sure it's all in one block.  Take out the user input for this minimal example and set the string to something static for debugging.  Then include the complete error message and stacktrace when it's run.

Comment: Do you realize how big the numbers are? For example, a standard `/64` IPv6 network has 18,446,744,073,709,551,616 addresses, and, if you can list 1,000,000 per second, it would take you over 584,542 years to list them all. A `/48` IPv6 prefix would have 65,536 times the addresses as a standard `/64` IPv6 network, so it would take that much longer to list them all. You simply do not have the RAM, disk space, or time to be able to do that.

Comment: Thanks Daniel & Ron for your feedback. I have edited code as advised. I do understand its huge no of addresses, However my aim to Obtain 1st 3 addresses and last address. Could you please direct me to alternative solution.

Comment: With IPv6, that is pretty simple. A standard IPv6 network is `/64`, and using network sizes other than can break IPv6 features (except for `/127` for point-to-point links, and `/128` for things like loopbacks). The first three addresses in any `/64` network would have `0:0:0:0`, `0:0:0:1`, and `0:0:0:2` as the last 64 bits of the address, and the last address would have `ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff` as the last address in the network.

Comment: Remember that the all-zeros network address is reserved for the [Router Anycast](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4291#section-2.6.1) address, and the last 128 addresses in the network are reserved for the [Subnet Anycast](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2526) addresses.